# How can I create a colour scheme based on two specific, adjacent(ish) colours?

Tags: website-design, color, color-theory, palette

I'm helping a friend to produce his website. He's supplied his logo and a flyer that he's used, which use the colour scheme he's opted for - green, blue and white. The specific colour values for the blue and green are:

## 00AEEF

[image: #00AEEF]

## 79BA55

[image: #79BA55]

Using those colours for on-page elements has had poor results for me.

I've tried to find a palette using Adobe Color CC, but can't get it to produce something using those two specific hex values. Unless I'm not using it properly, it looks like Color CC only creates schemes based on one chosen colour, rather than allowing me to specify two colours to work around.

So in these circumstances, given the specific colours I've been provided, how can or what can I use to create a satisfactory colour scheme from them?

Note that I'm not asking to create the same kind of/equivalent colour scheme for any other arbitrary colours.

Again - this is **NOT** the same question as the one asked [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33512/derive-color-palette-from-given-set-of-colors), which is asking if the calculations make sense. My question does not ask about calculations; I am asking how I can create a palette of complementing colours based on the two that I have been provided with.

Comment: Do you want to a mathematical solution? Or just a tool that will let you work with two core colours?

Comment: Benteh - I'm just looking for the latter. I appreciate @ZachSaucier 's suggestion, but after reading it, it sounds like the OP is asking to create the same kind of/equivalent colour scheme for any other arbitrary colours, which is a bit different to my question.

Comment: Fristly, I think you are forgetting to click 'custom' in Adobe Color. Secondly, creating a colour scheme is quite the art and detailing the process would be way too long for our Q&A format. I'd advice you to have a read of a series of articles starting [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/08/color-theory-for-designer-part-3-creating-your-own-color-palettes/) on Smashing Magazine to get a basic grasp of colour theory, terminology and schemes.

Comment: @Vincent - But how does clicking 'custom' help to identify additional colours for a given set? For me, it only lets me set colour values manually - it doesn't provide suggestions for additional values. I appreciate the basic concepts of colour theory, which I suppose is the basis for my question, as I've not found a tool or method for identifying analogous or complementary colours based on the two values I've been given. Likewise, I appreciate the difficulty of it (also hence my question); If it's too difficult to provide a systematic solution, then that's a perfectly valid answer to provide.

Comment: It doesn't. And yes, creating a colour scheme from two given colours is both art and science, like a lot of things in design. I'd seriously advice the third article in the series I mentioned to get an idea.

Comment: Do any of the answers [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/352/8708) provide the solution you're looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't quite provide a suitable answer, @JohnB. The question is similar, but it looks like the answers are mostly answering a different question (it looks like OP has been misunderstood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this, including mathematically, but here is an opinionated approach based on experience.

From a colour theory perspective both the brand blue and green have similar values (saturation/luminosity). I don't think you need any more bright colours in the palette. You could pick either as the primary colour.

Use the **primary colour** for call to action buttons and links. Use it sparingly to highlight the primary functions of the page.

Create tints (lighter) and shades (darker) of your **secondary colour** by adding white and RGB black in 20% increments. This gives you a choice of colours of varying intensities for colour blocks and structural elements.

[image]

You also need a neutral colour in your palette. This is often grey or sand, but you can add a tiny amount of green or blue to make the grey less boring. This is commonly used as a background to help define focal areas of the page.

I know a lot of designers would find this approach quite dull, but it's failsafe, and quite similar to the one taken in Google's Material Design.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your constructive input, @twigsta; that's a great help. Using one colour as primary, the other as secondary with gradations, and a neutral colour, sounds like a practical approach to my problem. It's not the most exciting palette, but it's functional - that's all that matters for this site, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use https://coolors.co/
You can add 2 custom colors and "lock" them. (I think you need to sign up to get that feature, tho for me it was free.)
You then hit spacebar and it suggests matching colors to complete the theme.

Comment: I think I've attempted that before, but I'll give it another try, thanks.