# Validation colors in the same family as my primary

Tags: website-design, color, website-templates

I am working on a web application and the particular shade of blue that is our company's primary color does not jive all that well with standard red, green, and yellow on the web. When I want to put up validation messages they look a bit out of place.

I tried using the Adobe color picker, but all of the compliments, compounds, etc. do not feature a red or green.

I'm looking for a red green and yellow shade that look like they they mesh with a primary. Are there tools for this? I'm leaving it generic so it can be more of a general question.

What tool/calculation can I use to find these?

Comment: Use colors with the same/similar saturation and luminosity like [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/66350/23061) suggests.Alternatively, you can [look for palettes](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/352/23061) that include your primary color and a red, green, and yellow and find some that fit

Comment: Tools?  Certainly - have you tried color(dot)adobe(dot)com? Try using the "Anologous" rule.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed this advice from Erica Schoonmaker before on how to unite colors into a more cohesive palette. https://dribbble.com/shots/166246-My-Secret-for-Color-Schemes

Take a selection of colors you want to add to your palette and use your primary color to tint them.

> Secret to cohesive color schemes: pick a bunch of colors you want to do (purple, blue, etc like you did here), then pick an overall color (let's say orange, for playfulness) that you want to tint everything towards... Overlay the "overall color" (or soft light, or whatever blending mode depending on if you want darker or lighter colors) and play with the opacity till you get something you can work with.